# Computing $\ E[Y^2] $ when $Y$ is a piecewise function of $X \sim Pois(2) $

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution, expected-value

$\ X \sim Pois(2) $ and let$\ Y $ be a random variable :  $\ Y = \begin{cases} 2X  , X \le 3 \\ X , X \ge 4 \end{cases} $

compute $\ E[Y^2] $ ?

I have calculated that $\ E[Y] = E[X] + 10e^{-2} $ and I have the identity $\ Var(X) = E[X^2] - (E[X])^2 $ and because $\ X $ is poisson then $\ Var(X) = E[X] $. but I'm not sure if $\ Y $ is also a poisson variable?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$Y$ cannot be Poisson, because for example, $$\Pr[Y = 3] = \Pr[2X = 3] = \Pr[X = 3/2] = 0.$$

If we define $Y$ as in the body of the post, i.e. $$Y = \begin{cases} 2X, & X \le 3 \\ X, & X \ge 4, \end{cases}$$ then we note that 
$$\begin{align*}\operatorname{E}[Y^2] 
&= \sum_{x=0}^3 (2x)^2 e^{-\lambda} \frac{\lambda^x}{x!} + \sum_{x=4}^\infty x^2 e^{-\lambda} \frac{\lambda^x}{x!} \\
&= 4 \sum_{x=0}^3 x^2 e^{-\lambda} \frac{\lambda^x}{x!} + \sum_{x=4}^\infty x^2 e^{-\lambda} \frac{\lambda^x}{x!} \\
&= 3 \sum_{x=0}^3 x^2 e^{-\lambda} \frac{\lambda^x}{x!} + \left(\sum_{x=0}^3 x^2 e^{-\lambda} \frac{\lambda^x}{x!} + \sum_{x=4}^\infty x^2 e^{-\lambda} \frac{\lambda^x}{x!} \right) \\
&= 3 \sum_{x=0}^3 x^2 e^{-\lambda} \frac{\lambda^x}{x!} + \sum_{x=0}^\infty x^2 e^{-\lambda} \frac{\lambda^x}{x!} \\
&= e^{-\lambda} (3\lambda + 6 \lambda^2 + \tfrac{9}{2} \lambda^3) + \operatorname{E}[X^2] \\
&= 66e^{-2} + \operatorname{E}[X]^2 + \operatorname{Var}[X] \\
&= 66e^{-2} + \lambda^2 + \lambda \\
&= 6 + 66e^{-2}.
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Could you explain to me why $\ (2x)^2 $ becomes $\ 3x^2 $ ?

Comment: @bm1125 I have expanded the details of that calculation in my edit, but simply put, $4 = 3 + 1.$

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
E[Y^2] 
&= \sum_{x=0}^3 (2x)^2 Pr(X=x)+ \sum_{x=4}^\infty x^2 Pr(X=x)\\
&=\sum_{x=0}^3 4x^2 Pr(X=x)+ \sum_{x=4}^\infty x^2 Pr(X=x)\\
&=\sum_{x=0}^3 3x^2 Pr(X=x)+ \sum_{x=0}^\infty x^2 Pr(X=x)\\
&=3\sum_{x=1}^3 x^2 Pr(X=x)+ E[X^2]\\
&= 3\left( Pr(X=1) + 4Pr(X=2)+9Pr(X=3) \right) + E[X^2]
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks for your answer! could you explain the second equality? I think you also miss the fact that $\ P\{X=6\} \not = P\{Y=6\} $ as $\ P\{Y=6\} = P\{X=3\} + P\{X=6\} $ I believe.

Comment: All of the summations should be with respect to $x$.

Comment: oops, i made lots of typos, thanks.

Comment: I use the law of the unconscious statistician $E[g(X)]=\sum_x g(x)P(X=x)$. For the line from $4x^$ to $3x^2$, we pass a copy of $x^2$ to the second term, hence there is change of the index.